# Why does room temperature coffee taste so bad, even to asnomics?

Tags: flavor, coffee, smell

It's been theorised that room temperature coffee tastes more bitter might be due to the smell sense being activated by hot coffee (particles moving around), which improves the taste.

However, as a congenital anosmic (no sense of smell since birth), room temperature / cold coffee is still awful.  I love a hot cup of coffee, on the other hand.

Any proven theories?

Comment: This is a question about the physiology or science of taste perception, not cooking or culinary arts.  It may fit better with Biology or one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - really? Comparable question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22327/why-does-cold-coffee-taste-sweeter-with-the-same-amount-of-sugar?rq=1

Comment: That is a pretty poor match too.

Comment: I think this is probably too subjective to answer. I actually prefer my coffee closer to room temperature as I think it tastes less bitter when cooled.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ indeed most of the related links on the right are quite similar - coffee after reheating, why food tastes bland when sick, why instant coffee tastes burnt etc...

Comment: You are asking about specific tastes in an abnormal condition, which takes this question much farther from the mainstream.  I get one vote; it takes four more.   You are also welcome to come to meta or chat to discuss it further.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I see your point, but I also think that a) as he implies, it would be perfectly reasonable for OP to look (many) extant examples, and conclude that this is OK/On-Topic and b) that this is an issue many here will find interesting (especially since aromatics/olfactory response is such a common/accepted answer for similar questions).   Granted, neither of thos points means you're wrong, although they *might* suggest a shift in the rules ... If you take it to Meta, please leave a link here.

Comment: @MarkMayo it may have something to do with your taste buds sensing range.  We know that they don't pick up bitter very well when cold (e.g cold vs warm beer) there may be the same effect on the other side of temperature range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial statement is too broad. It is not true that room temperature / cold coffee tastes awful. It is highly dependent on how good the roasted coffee is. This is why coffee cuppers drink coffee at room temperature.

ANY defects in the coffee are amplified as it cools. This is why almost everyone likes hot coffee. Unless you have really good coffee, you can detect off flavors and bitterness as it cools. With really good coffee, the flavors actually improve /expand as it cools.

Source - I roast my own coffee every week on a Hottop roaster. I drink coffee black, and I can drink my coffee cold with no problem. Can't say that about Starbucks, Dunkin Donuts, etc.